# Ajax don't transmit data

Tags: ajax, django, csrf-protection

I'm using ajax to pass data to a view for save in database.
In javascript the data look correct but in the view is null.
Read the comments in code for other questions and informations

My `javascript`:

```
...
var changed_element=[];
var changed_value=[];

document.getElementById('tabella').addEventListener('change', function(event){
    ...
    changed_element.push(element); //list of list of string
    changed_value.push(elem[elem.value].text); //list of string
    ...
});

document.getElementById('btn-save').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('changed_element', changed_element) //print the right value
  $.ajax({type: 'POST',
    url: '/salva-conoscenze-rapporti/',
    data: {
      changed_element: changed_element,
      changed_value: changed_value //<= comma?
    },
    success: function(msg) {
      console.log(msg) //prints 'It works'
      document.getElementById('btn-save').style.display = 'none';
    } //<= comma?
  });
});
```

My `view`:

```
@staff_member_required
@ensure_csrf_cookie #I need this?
def salva_conoscenze_rapporti(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        changed_element = request.POST.get('changed_element', None)
        changed_value = request.POST.get('changed_value', None)
        msg='it works'
        print(changed_element) #prints None instead of array
        print(changed_value)

    else:
        msg="it doesn't work"
    return HttpResponse(msg)
```

My `template base.html`:

```
...
<script>
  var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
  function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
  }
  $.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
      if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
      }
    }
  });
</script>
...
```

My `template`:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
...
```

Basically `print(changed_element)` should gives the data instead gives `None`.

My `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in `settings.py`:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

My variables:

```
changed_element=[ [ "conoscenza", "Cliente1", "Cliente2" ] ];

changed_value=[ "Generale" ];
```

`console.log(changed_element)` gives: `Array [ Array[3] ]`

Comment: well this can't be your real code because there is a glaring syntax eerror. if you post your real code you might find a solution

Comment: Sorry, it's just simplified... Ah, maybe you say the msg... I translate that

Comment: Maybe the scope of variables in javascript? or something in the csrf?

Answer (score 0):

To get the cookie you also can use with jQuery

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

And then, I'll correcting your script.

```
// $('.btn-save').click(function() { // to simply with jquery
document.getElementById('btn-save').addEventListener('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/salva-conoscenze-rapporti/',
    data: {
      "changed_element"    : changed_element,
      "changed_value"      : changed_value,
      "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrftoken // from `var csrftoken;`
    },
    success: function(msg) {
      console.log(msg) //prints 'It works'
      document.getElementById('btn-save').style.display = 'none';
    } //<= comma?
  });
});
```

Or like this one:

```
$('.btn-save').click(function() {
  var form = new FormData();
  form.append('changed_element', changed_element);
  form.append('changed_value', changed_value);
  form.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', getCookie('csrftoken'));

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/salva-conoscenze-rapporti/',
    data: form,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(msg) {
      console.log(msg) //prints 'It works'
      document.getElementById('btn-save').style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
});
```

In your `views.py`

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

@csrf_protect
@staff_member_required
def salva_conoscenze_rapporti(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        changed_element = request.POST.get('changed_element', None)
        changed_value = request.POST.get('changed_value', None)
        msg = 'it works'
        print(changed_element)
        print(changed_value)
    else:
        msg="it doesn't work"
    return HttpResponse(msg)
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: You would have got my upvote if this question was about 403 forbidden error often seen with CSRF. Unfortunately that's not what the OP is complaining about

Comment: Even with your change it doesn't work... maybe something about the format of the variables? I should convert them in some way? I edited my post with the MIDDLEWARE and variables

Comment: hembbb... if like that, the focused error at your dictionary of `data`. makesure the `key` included with string.. `"changed_element" = changed_element`.